# 3 month notice versus 1 month notice

Tags: contract-law, india

I do not want to serve a complete notice period (3 months) for the MNC (multi-national company) in India I currently work for. I would like to serve only one month notice period, and although I am ready to pay for not completing the full notice period, HR is not allowing me to do this. Instead, they keep insisting that I need to complete the full notice period. This is creating an issue for me and it is not allowing a smooth transition for my new job.

What legal action can be taken?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for here; can you rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your employment contract. If there is a provision in your employment contract stating you can leave before notice period by paying certain amount money, No one can stop you from leaving.

Comment: This is India. Employment laws there can be awful for employees.

Comment: including indentured servitude?

Comment: In all but name, yes.